# Eclipse Kepler runs weird

Tags: 13.10, eclipse

I just downloaded and try to run Eclipse Kepler on Ubuntu 13.10. 
If I run Eclipse with command

```
./eclipse
```

Eclipse runs, but very weird :(

[image: Eclipse Kepler on Ubuntu 13.10]

Nut if I run with the command

```
sudo ./eclipse
```

everything runs fine. But I don't want to `sudo`. Please help me.

Comment: Could you please [add](http://askubuntu.com/posts/364310/edit) what is weird about your eclipse?

Comment: Does this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19452969/menu-in-eclipse-does-not-work-ubuntu-13-10) apply to your problem?

Comment: Thanks Mike, i resolved it by your recommend post, I use this command: UBUNTU_MENUPROXY= /home/huynq2/Downloads/eclipse/eclipse

Answer (score 1):

## How to workaround Eclipse on Ubuntu 13.10 bug

As I can't flag this question as a duplicate of this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19452969/menu-in-eclipse-does-not-work-ubuntu-13-10). I'm lifting the answer for completeness sake (with some reformatting).

This bug has been [confirmed](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/unity/+bug/1221848) in Ubuntu 13.10.

In order to overcome problem, you have to change your `eclipse.desktop` file in part of Exec passing `env UBUNTU_MENUPROXY` with the Eclipse path and Eclipse will be runnable from the launcher with a functional menu bar.

Here is pattern for changing eclipse.desktop file:

```
Exec=env UBUNTU_MENUPROXY= path/to/eclipse
```

Answer (score 1):

If you change the **Exec** line in the Eclipse.desktop file you don't need to write it manually every time. In my case I found that there were three versions of eclipse.desktop file. I had to change all of them to make it work.

There are two versions in /usr/share/applications:

```
eclipse.desktop
Eclipse.desktop
```

Either delete one of them, or change the Exec line in both of them as described above.
The third version is in the home folder:

```
~/.local/share/applications/Eclipse.desktop
```

You can either delete this last one or change the **Exec** line in this one too.

All you have to do is change the **Exec** line as follows:

```
Exec=env UBUNTU_MENUPROXY= /path/to/eclipse/eclipse
```

Answer (score 0):

[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Name=Eclipse
Exec=env UBUNTU_MENUPROXY= eclipse
Terminal=false
Icon=/opt/eclipse/icon.xpm
Type=Application
Categories=IDE;Development
X-Ayatana-Desktop-Shortcuts=NewWindow
[NewWindow Shortcut Group]
Name=New Window
Exec=env UBUNTU_MENUPROXY= eclipse
TargetEnvironment=Unity

it will work certainly... enjoy java coding..on ubuntu 13.10